# Font symbol (Wingdings3) not working within SSRS ReportViewer Webpart

Tags: web-part, reporting-services, provisioning

We have an SSRS report that uses the `Wingdings3` font for rendering arrow signs in a table. In the SSRS Preview pane, the table renders fine:

[image: Preview]

However, on the Sharepoint page where the report is included in a report-viewer webpart, the `Wingdings3` font doesn't get picked up, and instead we get this:

[image: Actual]

How can we ensure that the symbol/font is rendered fine on the page? The page in question here has been created using webpart provisioning and a custom layout, so is there a way to incorporate the css for including the required font? Alternatively, could the font be explicitly included in the report-viewer webpart properties? Any other suggestions?

Comment: Does this report will be rendered as HTML or as an image?

Comment: @StefanBauer: The report is interactive, and is rendered as HTML on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I finally figured this. (And now that I've figured it, the solution seems so obvious I wonder why I didn't figure this out before!)*

It so happened that the Sharepoint site we were deploying our page to had a poorly written Master.CSS file where the font 'Arial' was being applied to all `<div>` tags! As a result, the cell within which the Wingdings font was to be rendered was rendering in Arial.

[image: Wingdings3 overridden by Arial]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you use a custom style sheet in the report but it look like somehow the windings was not assigned to the cell. Instead the default font of the report has been used.

There is a similar post where custom style sheet couldn't been loaded on another stack exchange forum.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959904/attaching-external-style-sheet-to-a-html-page-in-ssrs-and-report-manager

Comment: Thank you very much, Stefan. Your line in your answer, `it looks like somehow the windings was not assigned to the cell. Instead the default font of the report has been used` caused me to delve into the HTML of the cell using inspector, and unearth the real cause of the issue (see my answer). I've awarded you the bounty!